# implicit declaration of function ‘usleep’

Tags: c, warnings, usleep

So i've been looking stuff about `usleep()` and all I have found to get rid of this is `#define` which i have done... Any ohter suggestion? I need to get rid of this warning... Or any ideas on how to use sleep with miliseconds.

```
#define _BSB_SOURCE
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

int r = rand() % 1000 +1;
usleep(r*1000);        
pthread_mutex_lock (&count_mutex);
```

Comment: There is no `_BSB_SOURCE` macro, it's `_BSD_SOURCE` and it's deprecated.

Answer (score 7):

You need to remove `-std=c99` from your compiler command or use the `_XOPEN_SOURCE` macro before including `unistd.h`.

If you want you can use `-std=gnu99` instead of `-std=c99`.

Answer (score 2):

[nanosleep()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40451160/5165135) worked for me:

> On a relevant note: usleep() has been removed since POSIX-2008 and
>   recommends to use nanosleep() instead.