# Error using the usleep function as the compiler says " 'usleep' was not declared in this scope despite" including all needed libraries

Tags: c, libraries, usleep

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    printf("test");
    usleep(1000000);
    printf("test");


    return 0;
}
```

I am being told "error: 'usleep' was not declared in this scope". I am using the c free compiler if that makes a difference and am completely unsure of why this code is not compiling as all needed libraries are included.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [implicit declaration of function usleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10053788/implicit-declaration-of-function-usleep)

Comment: errors: "EINVAL usec is not smaller than 1000000.  (On systems where that is considered an error.)"

Comment: you can use Sleep(1000);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40451160/215752

Comment: I cannot use Sleep(1000); as I am on a unix system, additionally I recieve the same error

Comment: Thanks for the answer Hogan :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a Windows equivalent of nanosleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7827062/is-there-a-windows-equivalent-of-nanosleep)

Comment: Why `#include <windows.h>` if you are on a Unix system?

Comment: if you are in linux use #include <unistd.h>  // UNIX standard function definitions